# What is this feeling called?

Tags: idioms, american-english, phrasal-verbs

> I believe good brands are usually expensive; however, cheaper brands
>   aren't durable so they hardly satisfy.

Is this just a belief, or is it something else?

Comment: It's called _prudence._

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this particular *feeling* or *belief* has a name. But you could say that *you believe*

> [*you get what you pay for.*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you+get+what+you+pay+for)
>   *Prov. Cliché* If you do not pay much money for something, it is probably of poor quality.; If you pay well for something, it is more likely to be of good quality.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this context, your belief is based on the feeling of trust, which may be based on your own or your friends' past experience, or someone's authoritative opinion, or the saying [*"If you buy quality, you only cry once" / "If you buy cheaply, you pay dearly"*](http://www.englishdaily626.com/proverbs.php?010).

You could also say that  you are confident (have *a feeling* of confidence) about what you're saying. If this confidence (or belief) is *just* intuitive, it may be called ["a hunch"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hunch) or ["a gut feeling"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gut-feeling).